# Click on NSBezierPath

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nsbezierpath

I'm drawing a NSBezierPath line on my NSImageView. I'm creating NSBezierPath object, setting `moveToPoint`, setting `lineToPoint`, setting `setLineWidth:` and after that in `drawRect` of my `NSImageView` subclass I'm calling `[myNSBezierPath stroke]`. It all works just like I want, but I can't seem to use `containsPoint:` method... I tried implementing

```
if([myNSBezierPath containsPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow]]{
   //do something
}
```

in `-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent*)theEvent` of my NSImageView subclass but it's never reacting and I'm sure I'm hitting that line... Am I doing something wrong? I just need to detect if NSBezierPath is being clicked.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to transform the mouse click location into the coordinate system of your image view subclass, not into the one of the window (unless they are the same). Your bezier path doesn't know about the offset it's drawn into, so you have to take that into account when performing a hit test.

Also, from the [`containsPoint:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBezierPath/containsPoint%3a) documentation:

> This method checks the point against the path itself and the area it
>   encloses. When determining hits in the enclosed area, this method uses
>   the non-zero winding rule (NSNonZeroWindingRule). **It does not take
>   into account the line width used to stroke the path.**

Emphasis mine.

Comment: ImageView is the same size as the window (same rect because I'm using it for a background), so I think that is not the problem... Should I be able to detect NSBezierLine in mouseEvent hitTest? I'm printing classes of everything that is being clicked on and I can never get NSBezierPath.